# Use of Encrypted Fields in List views and Reports

Tags: encryption, platform-encryption

Am I able to use Encrypted Fields in filter criteria in list views, reports and communities? Is there documentation anywhere I can find? I want to verify before rolling out encryption?

Answer (score 3):

There are various limits on listview / reports when using [deterministic encryption](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_pe_deterministic_considerations.htm&type=5)

In particular, you can not do:

- Filter on Contains or Starts With or any relative operator (>, < >=, <=)
- Use the column sort on any encrypted field in a listview (as Order BY is not supported). This does not affect reports, only ListViews

*I strongly suggest doing this in a sandbox and testing first.*

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you encrypt a field with deterministic encryption you can filter on that field in list views and reports (and even SOQL if you need).

The documentation for deterministic encryption is [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_pe_deterministic_overview.htm&type=5).